# Correct use of COALESCE in postgres / COALESCE not working correctly

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

I am trying to return an hourly report on the number of searches performed. My results do not include the hours when there are zero searches, I thought I had the syntax correct for using COALESCE. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
SELECT CAST(startdatetime as Date),extract(hour from startdatetime) as hr, COALESCE(count(distinct id),0) as average_per_hour
FROM search WHERE CAST(startdatetime As Date) = '2014/07/05' 
GROUP BY CAST(startdatetime as Date),extract(hour from startdatetime) 
ORDER BY CAST(startdatetime as Date),extract(hour from startdatetime)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you expect it to show data that isn't there?

Comment: I thought the point of coalesce was that it returns a zero if the result is null/isn't there?

Comment: Yes, but for that to work "something" must be returned. But if you don't have a row in the table there is nothing coalesce could work with. `select coalesce(null, 42) where false` --> no rows returned.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the `coalesce()` function. Have a look at `generate_series()` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: Oh ok, I get you now. Any advice on how I could achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some refinement, but basically the same as @a_horse_with_no_name's answer:

```
SELECT DATE '2014-07-05', hr, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS average_per_hour
FROM generate_series(0, 23) hr
LEFT JOIN search ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM startdatetime) = hr AND CAST(startdatetime AS DATE) = '2014-07-05' 
GROUP BY hr
ORDER BY hr
```

Using `CAST(startdatetime AS DATE)` in `ORDER BY` & `GROUP BY` is irrelevant, because you search only one day. If that is not the case in general, you will need to tweak `generate_series()` too.

**Edit**:

This works across multiple days:

```
SELECT CAST(hr AS DATE), EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hr), COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS average_per_hour
FROM generate_series('2014-07-05 00:00:00', '2014-07-06 23:00:00', INTERVAL '1' HOUR) hr
LEFT JOIN search ON date_trunc('hour', startdatetime) = hr
GROUP BY hr
ORDER BY hr
```

Comment: Thanks pozs, that query returns the same results I was getting before though. Do I need to include the coalesce too? I tried that also and got the same results.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a "lookup" table with all the hours in a day. Then you do a left join against your search table. Due to the left join on all possible rows, you can include the "missing" hours as well.

Something like the following (**not tested, there might be syntax errors!**)

```
with hours as (
  select hr
  from generate_series(0,23) hr
)
SELECT CAST(search.startdatetime as Date), 
       hours.hr, 
       count(distinct search.id) as average_per_hour
FROM hours 
  left join search on extract(hour from search.startdatetime) = hours.hr
WHERE cast(startdatetime As Date) = date '2014-07-05' 
GROUP BY cast(startdatetime as Date),extract(hour from startdatetime) 
ORDER BY CAST(startdatetime as Date),extract(hour from startdatetime);
```

As shown this will only work if you select exactly one day.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that up, the syntax was fine, it still only returned the same results though :(